# Paypal sometimes popup or inline when the black Debit/Credit button is clicked

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm new to payment integration using Paypal. I enabled the card to accept payments to both debit and credit card. I set the locale to Germany and intent=capture. When clicking the Debit/Credit Card black button, only the form for Credit Card is available and there's not an option to pay using Debit Card.

Based on the what I tested here
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/responsive.
The payment through debit will be available when there's a popup.
The popup is showing only if i click really fast on "black credit/debit cart" before it ends the animation where the text (Debit or Credit Card) appears. If I clicked late, it will show a form below the button that only accepts Credit Card payment.

Is there a way to force the behavior to popup a new window when Debit/Credit Card black button is clicked? This way, both debit and credit payment will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The Debit or Credit Card button will always open a form when available, and only fall back to a popup when there is an error or it is not available.

The only button that will always open a popup is the yellow PayPal one.

Comment: I tried to click the Debit/Credit button as fast as I could before the text appears and it opens a popup. I tried paying using Debit sandbox from that and it's working. Maybe it's a bug on paypal.

Comment: Clicking fast is triggering an error condition. The inline form accepts most international debit cards, perhaps not German ones. In any case, there are other buttons for German payment methods, including a SEPA one.